# Feature Vectors representation

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, feature-engineering

I would like to know I how you represent a feature vector like this dataset wise. The vector length is dynamic but the each element has a fixed length (9). For xgboost implementation, do I just create columns for each of these features? Or is there any way to encode this vectores so they're readable for this kind of model?

[image]